# How to listen to other WiFi network SSIDs broadcasted via devices around using NodeMCU?

Tags: lua, wifi, esp8266, nodemcu

Devices [broadcast SSIDs of networks they connected to previosly.](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/62126/35146) I wonder how to listen to such broadcasts using NodeMCU Lua API ("set the network card in monitor mode")?

Answer (score 3):

I saw other people post about "ESP8266 in sniffer mode". It seems to be possible if you work directly with the Espressif SDK instead of NodeMCU. NodeMCU does not have a monitor mode, see [API docs](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/wifi/#wifisetmode).

There's a Espressif whitepaper called "[ESP8266 Sniffer Introduction](http://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/esp8266-technical_reference_en_0.pdf#page=108)".

You might also want to take a look at the following two repositories:

- https://github.com/Informatic/esp8266-sniffer
- https://github.com/CHERTS/esp8266-devkit/tree/master/Espressif/examples/wifi-sniffer